# Volume Scatter leaves black fringe

Tags: node-editor, volumetrics

quite the blender noob here:
I am trying to achieve a fog effect with volume scatter in blender 3.0, because principled volume supposedly doesnt work in blender 3.0.

below you can see the problem:
Where the Fog - Cube intersects the Elevation Model there is a black fringe around the hills, I have to rid of this one but dont know how. Any help is appreciated.
If it helps, there´s also a screenshot of my nodes setup.

Thank you in advance :)
[image]
[image]

Comment: You would have to share your simplified file, because I tried your material and seems to be fine, your issue lays elsewhere https://imgur.com/65WEQPA ... share just a scene with default cube and cube with volumetric material with such issue. use https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Based on that I recreated a simple file where the issue was not recreated. Then I checked the other material properties and disabled ambienct occlusion, which resolved the problem.